# Ionic 2 native feature debugging

Tags: ionic2

I am writing an app using native functionalities. However, I am finding errors within my app when debugging these features.

How do I debug native features in ionic 2? I could not find good answers.

Comment: what errors are you getting?

Comment: Emulate your app with `ionic run android -l -c`. l is for livereload and c is for console logs. Replace android with your system. So you will see all the console logs in your terminal. I had to change the `package.json` and replace `ionic:serve` with `ionic:watch`

Comment: Hi @DennisKoch please add it as an answer so I can upvote it :D

Comment: Didnt think your problem is solved so fast :D

Comment: Also 'adb' could be used for native debugging.

Comment: @DennisKoch I didnt think so too.... :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emulate your app with `ionic run android -l -c`.

-l is for livereload and -c is for console logs. Replace android with your system. So you will see all the console logs in your terminal.

I had to change the `package.json` and replace `ionic:serve` with `ionic:watch`

Comment: Hi, may I know is it the same for IOS?